# How to drag a window from any point (maybe with shortcut)

Tags: mac, windows, ui

Is there any setting or application that would let me drag a window without having to go to the window title bar?

Maybe some application may let me drag a window by holding FN (or other combination) and then dragging the window from any point.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7549/raise-lower-move-resize-windows-with-mouse-modifier-keys - especially the suggestion for [Zooom/2](http://coderage-software.com/zooom/index.html) - should do what you're after

Comment: Thanks mikej, I chose [Easy move+resize](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/176682/145520). Really simple, just what I was looking for.